# jQuery script works after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming

I use this code to change the text of an element, but it only works I refreshing the page how could i make it work without refreshing.?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("Show all", "OLA"); 
  });    
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask] pages.  Your problem isn't very clear - "it works after I reload" - so does it *only* work on a reload?  Should it *not* work on a reload ("it *still* works on reload")?   What should it do that it isn't?  What should it not do that it is?

Comment: Issues like this are normally caused by caching. Check that the jQuery (or any other script reference) doesn't have an `async` attribute on it, also check that you're using callbacks/promises correctly if there's any async content in the page. Other than that, there's not much diagnosis we can offer with the information in the question.

Comment: Yeah,i am sorry.I mean it works when i refreshing the page,i mean when i am visiting the page there aren't any changes and when i am refreshing the page it there are,i want the script to run when i am visiting the page @freedomn-m